# Using SIGINT to kill a function in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, asynchronous, subprocess, python-asyncio

Take the following code as an example:

```
import signal
import time

def stop(signal, frame):
    print("You pressed ctrl-c")
    # stop counter()

def counter():
    for i in range(20):
        print(i+1)
        time.sleep(0.2)

signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, stop)
while True:
    if(input("Do you want to count? ")=="yes"):
        counter()
```

How would I get the `stop()` function to kill, or break, the `counter()` function so it returns to the prompt?

Output example:

```
Do you want to count? no
Do you want to count? yes
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
You pressed ctrl-c
Do you want to count?
```

I'm using Python 3.5.2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `KeyboardInterrupt` exception instead of defining your own `SIGINT` handler:

```
while input("Do you want to count? ").strip().casefold() == "yes":
    try:
        counter()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("You pressed ctrl-c")
```

Comment: I really like this for the amount of space it saves :)

Answer (score 2):

You could raise an exception in `stop` which will halt execution of `counter` and search for the closest exception handler (which you set in the `while True` loop).

That is, create a custom exception:

```
class SigIntException(BaseException): pass
```

Raise it in `stop`:

```
def stop(signal, frame):
    print("You pressed ctrl-c")
    raise SigIntException
```

and catch it in your `while` loop:

```
while True:
    if(input("Do you want to count? ")=="yes"):
        try:        
            counter()
        except SigIntException:
            pass
```

and it behaves the way you need it to.

Comment: Genius! Thanks for the help ;D

Comment: @EddieHart to be clear, the default SIGINT handler in Python raises KeyboardInterrupt exception i.e., you don't need to do anything by default to interrupt your `counter()` function in the main thread.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian Yes, but as far as I am aware this would terminate the entire program?

Comment: @EddieHart: if you want to continue; use `try/except KeyboardInterrupt` like with any other exception in Python.